# How to overclock Raspberry Pi 3 running Android Things?

Tags: overclocking, android-things

I know *Raspberry Pi* 3 can be overclocked on the *Raspbian* OS by tweaking the `config.txt` file. But is there a way to overclock *Raspberry Pi* 3 running the *Android Things*?

Comment: Have you tried _"tweaking `config.txt`"_ that resides in the `/boot` partition of an _Android Things_ image?

Comment: okay, I didn't know that there was a config.txt on the Android Things image but it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to *Raspbian* OS you can *"tweak"* `config.txt` residing in the `/boot` partition of an *Android Things* image.